# Приложение не хочет устанавливаться на android 6.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

Здравствуйте.Приложение нормально устанавливается , работает и отлаживается на версиях 4.2.2 JB API-17, 4.4.2 KitKat api-19, 7.0 Nougat api-25. А в android 6.0 api-23 из AStudio не заливается.А при установке из файловой системы не запускается.При отладке из AStudio пишет вот это :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForRelease'.
> ProGuard configuration parser error: C:\Users\zverek\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-base-11.8.0.aar\570bfc4949f1aa304f53e08361663ee8\proguard.txt line 3:88 no viable alternative at input '<fields>
```

'в одном месте использую `GOOGLE-MAPS`.Почему он ругается?

Comment: Судя по логам возникает проблема при обфускации кода средствами proguard - попробуйте сначала без обфускации

Comment: СПС.попробую...

Comment: Зачем включать ProGuard при отладке?

Comment: Просто для показа нужно было подписать.Там был один сервис и нужно было его потестить, где то читал что сервис нужно тестить только в релиз версии.При подписке поставил галки на дебаг, в релиз версии.Вот и появились эти строки..А я на это особого внимания не уделял.Щас все вроде работает на 6-ом андроиде.Но именно на тот аппарат не проверял..Вечером проверю на нем.